# Twilio twiml record trim option not working

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Using Nodejs, I'm sending the following twiml. My understanding from Twilio's documentation is that with the *trim* option when the recordingStatusCallback function is called, the parameter RecordingDuration should be 0 if the user remains silent during the 7 seconds Twilio is recording. What I'm finding is the RecordingDuration is 7 and the recording itself is 7 seconds of silence, so I can't even use the mp3 file length to determine if the user said nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
      <Play>xyz.mp3</Play>
      <Record maxLength="30" finishOnKey="#" 
       timeout="7" 
       trim="trim-silence" 
       action="terminateTranscriptions" 
       transcribeCallback="procTranscribeEnglish" 
       recordingStatusCallbackEvent="completed absent" 
       recordingStatusCallBack="recordingStatusCallBack"/>
      <Say>I'm sorry. I didn't get your message. Goodbye.</Say>
 </Response>
```

Comment: There's not exactly a question here, but since it also is to do with how Twilio itself works, I reckon it would be best to get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to find out what is going on with trimming recordings.

Answer (score 1):

I tested TwiML similar to your own.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
      <Say>Welcome to the machine.</Say>
      <Record
        maxLength="30"
        timeout="6" 
        trim="trim-silence"
        action="https://example.com/echo1"
        method="GET"
        recordingStatusCallback="https://example.com/echo2"
        recordingStatusCallbackMethod="GET"
              />
 </Response>
```

My results:

If silence only,

- The call RecordingDuration (from the action URL) was the same as the timeout, example: 6 seconds.
- The recordingStatusCallBack RecordingDuration was the same as the timeout, example: 6 seconds.

If I left a short message and disconnected,

- The call RecordingDuration (from the action URL) was the same as the length of the short message, example: 2 seconds.
- The recordingStatusCallBack RecordingDuration was the length of the short message, example: 2 seconds.

If a short message and silence,

- The call RecordingDuration (from the action URL) was the same as the timeout + the length of the short message, example: 8 seconds (2 second message + 6 seconds timeout value).
- The recordingStatusCallBack RecordingDuration was the same as the timeout, example: 2 seconds.

Workaround, that will probably work,
   If the RecordingDuration is the same for action URL and the recordingStatusCallBack, and they equal the timeout length, then the odds are, no message was left.